# Problems in accessing the current location of user using Ext.util.Geolocation

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am working on an application which runs in a browser and get the current location of user.
(A production build kept on a server and accessing it using the corresponding URL)
While running the application using this url, the geolocation is not working.

For understanding geolocation, I referred to Sencha GeoCongress application accessible at below location.
URL : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/geocongress/

Case 1: 
When I tried to access the above URL in chrome browser of my desktop, it says, "geolocation unavailable. Setting your default location to sencha HQ".

Case2: I tried to run the same URL in native/chrome browser of android S2/S3 phones. I am not able to get the geolocation.

In both the cases, I am allowing website to track my physical location.

Question : Is it possible for an sencha application to access the current location of user, when the application is running in browser and the geolocation implementation is done using Ext.util.Geolocation?

or do I need to use navigator apis in java-script for achieving the same.

Appreciate any help in this regard. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It probably because your browser is set to "not" allow sending of your geo-location

Comment: As mentioned in 5th line from bottom, I allowed website to track my physical location.